# Can the TPL run the Task on more than one thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Mono/Xamarin-specific answers are welcomed.

I'm running System.Threading.Tasks using Task.Run(). Will The TPL assign the created task to a single thread for the life of the task's execution? Or is it possible that the created task will get preempted while running, and then be scheduled again on a different thread?

Will Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId be constant over the life of a Task?

Is the answer different for long-running tasks?

Is there a way to control TPL behavior in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will The TPL assign the created task to a single thread for the life of the task's execution?

The guideline is that *synchronous* portions of work run on a single thread. So, if you pass a synchronous delegate to `Task.Run`, it will all run on a single thread:

```
await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000)); // same thread after sleep
```

However, if you have asynchronous code, every `await` is a location in the code where the method is suspended. When the method resumes, it will resume on a thread pool thread (which may be a different thread).

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(5000)); // thread may change
```

The long-running flag (which cannot be passed to `Task.Run`) does not affect this behavior because it only applies to the first synchronous portion.

The normal way to control this is by using a custom `TaskScheduler` or `SynchronizationContext`. However, before going down that road, you may want to consider an alternative approach. There should be a better solution than forcing the method back onto the same thread. For example, thread-affine synchronization primitives all have `async`-compatible equivalents, thread-local storage can be replaced by closures / class fields / logical call context, etc.

Comment: It's worth noting that technically speaking, in your second example, `Run` is still executing the entirety of the delegate that it receives on a single thread.  It is the delegate that you passed to `Run` that explicitly defined it's behavior as doing something and then scheduling an operation to be performed in another thread pool thread, so it's still entirely correct to say that `Run` will only execute the delegate that you give it on a single thread, although various other types of tasks can represent actions performed on multiple threads.

Comment: I believe you and Servy are correct, and the closest that I can come to "proving" it is that the C# lock (obj) construct would not work properly if a synchronous delegate were ever run on more than one thread. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: The basic concept of `async` (where `await` is a "yield point") is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx). The `Task.Run` async/sync delegates are discussed briefly on [Stephen Toub's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

`Task.Run` will schedule the delegate to be executed in the thread pool, and the thread pool will only ever execute the given delegate on a single thread.  It won't move it around between threads.

That said, a `Task` conceptually is merely the representation of the completion of some asynchronous operation at some point in the future.  It can represent *anything* that finishes  eventually.  If you want to create a task that represents the execution of one delegate on one thread, then the execution of another delegate on a different thread, then you absolutely can do that.

Many methods using the `async` keyword will in fact do that.  Since, in an application that doesn't have a synchronization context set, the continuations wired up as a result of `await` calls may (they can sometimes be optimized out) each be scheduled separately in the thread pool.  For example, the following code run in a console app generates a task that could potentially print out three entirely different numbers.  (Of course, they aren't *required* to be different; the thread pool could just happen to schedule the continuations to run on the same thread.)

```ccharp
public static async Task Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Comment: How do you know this with certainty: "It won't move it around between threads."?

Comment: Well, first off, it couldn't really.  When you tell a thread to execute a delegate there is no mechanism to just execute half of it and then stop, without cooperation.  The logical C# thread could potentially not have a 1:1 mapping with an OS thread (although I'm pretty confident that that won't actually happen), but that's beyond layer's of abstraction that you really need to even know about anyway.  And if it could possibly change the thread executing your code (which it can't) that shouldn't break your program.  If it did, you'd almost certainly be doing something you shouldn't be.

Comment: So basically, you don't know it with certainty (that is okay). I don't know the implementation of TPL, but I could imagine that a long-running Task could be preempted, and then continued later due to a finite number of threads. I might guess that the TPL could choose a different thread to continue executing the task. As for your ability to tell that "you'd almost certainly be doing something you shouldn't be" without understanding any of the context, dude, that is amazing. You should find a way to monetize that skill.

Comment: @jeff7091 I do know that the thread pool won't execute the given operation on multiple threads.  Threads pause and continue later all the time, but they don't pause and then execute *another thread's* state.  And yes, even without knowing the context I can be quite confident that if you're writing code in a multithreaded environment with the expectation that it execute on a particular thread, the odds are *very* high that you're doing something that you shouldn't be as the entire point of using these layers of abstraction is to abstract away such concepts.

Comment: @jeff7091 I understand your thinking. It is probably not possibly to find the fact documented that the TPL will not move *running code* across threads. It could theoretically do that with cooperation from the runtime. On the other hand: a) there is hardly need to do that (do you disagree?) b) it would be hard to implement c) this would be detectable by user code because ManagedThreadId could change at any time d) unmanaged code couldn't deal with that and .NET calls into unmanaged code all the time. => The TPL does not do that. I cannot offer you an official source. Source: Servy and me.

Comment: @Servy, I want to make sure that I can allocate a SQLite DB conn on a per-thread basis w/the guarantee that the task (synchronous) will be kept on a single thread. Not exactly "doing something that you shouldn't". Please keep your opinions to yourself. I come to this site to get facts.

Comment: @jeff7091 You really shouldn't be allocating hard threads yourself ever.  Just use a connection pool, and the idea of a connection pool shouldn't be to bind a connection to each thread, but rather to bind the temporary use of a particular connection to each logical query.

Comment: @servy go read up on SQLite no-mutex concurrency and threads.